# Остановить работу функции если отменена загрузка страницы Flask

Tags: python, flask

У меня в программе есть route, в котором выполняется долгая функция, приведу такой пример:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

def my_func():
    for i in range(250):
        if not i % 2 == 0:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(5)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    my_func()
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Допустим,пользователь отменил загрузку `/home`, потому что, например, она загружался слишком долго. Но, если даже пользователь отменит загрузку страницы, функция продолжит свою работу.

Можно ли как-то 'отменить' работу этой функции если загрузка страницы отменена?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прямой ответ: **нет**, нельзя.

Развёрнутый ответ. Дело в том, что так устроены WSGI и существующее ПО, работающее с HTTP – никто в них не закладывал высокоуровневый функционал обработки прерывания соединений. Они работают так, что приложение сначала пишет полный ответ, затем передаёт его на уровни ниже, а там уже по возможности отправляется ответ.

---

[image: Layers]

Но теоретически отслеживать разрыв соединения можно, ведь где-то в глубине это происходит. Более детально узнать об этом можно в исследуя протоколы передачи данных, исходные коды библиотек, и немного по ссылкам ниже:

- Google Groups 2009: [Cancelling a request if client closes http socket](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/modwsgi/jr2ayp0xesk/QtINxMi_KUAJ)
- Reddit, Python 2015: [Terminate Flask function when window closes](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2e1e4k/terminate_flask_function_when_window_closes/)
- enSO 2015: [Flask: What happens when a user closes the browser while a long process is being executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28318084/5308802)

<sub>Вполне возможно, что в моём ответе содержатся неточности, т.к я не мега-специалист по этой теме, поэтому замечания принимаются.</sub>

---

Варианты решения:

1. Есть упомянутая выше гипотетическая возможность залезь под капот.
2. Отправлять запрос уже загруженной страницей, а в ней можно ловить событие закрытия и отправлять соответствующий запрос, настройку которого можно реализовать на сервере.
3. Разбить задачу на несколько отдельных запросов – тогда по закрытию страницы последующие запросы просто не будут отправлены.
4. Произвести сложные вычисления заранее, отправляя в момент запроса готовый результат.
5. Реализовать большие запросы по WebSocket'ам – у них вроде есть обработка разрыва соединения.

   Описанные варианты довольно сложны (особенно первые два) и не всегда возможны (следующие два), поэтому многие делают так:
6. Просто оставить всё как есть – ведь вычислительные ресурсы в наше время не слишком дорогие.

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ! Как по Вашему,можно ли создать функцию по типу check_connection() в файле сервера,и затем импортировав ее в файл функции, например, в цикле проверять, есть ли соединение?

Comment: @PythonNewbie Пожалуйста! Мне самому было интересно покопаться в теме. По вопросу: теоретически возможно, но это слишком сложно и костыльно, ненадёжно, поэтому советую подумать о вариантах 3,4 и особенно 6 :) Лично я всегда выбираю что-то из них.